# Does streaming large result sets with NHibernate actually work?

Tags: nhibernate, stream, resultset

I'm using the method that ayende proposed here:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/27/nhibernate-streaming-large-result-sets.aspx

on SQL Server 2005 with NHibernate 3.0.

My tests (trying to stream a result set with 10,000,000 items) indicate that the results are not being streamed (it appears the entire result set is loaded into memory first).

How can I get this to work? I will accept any solution that permits streaming of result sets in NHibernate, it doesn't have to be exactly ayende's solution.

Comment: some ADO.Net cache the results in memory, not sure if the built in does

Answer (score 2):

You can stream results from Linq with the following extension method with NH 4.0.0.4000 (Pass `ISessionImplementor` in if you don't like the reflection hack):

```
public static EnumerableImpl Stream<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    var provider = ((NhQueryable<T>) source).Provider as DefaultQueryProvider;
    var sessionImpl = (ISessionImplementor)provider.GetType()
        .GetProperty("Session", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(provider);
    var expression = new NhLinqExpression(source.Expression, sessionImpl.Factory);
    var query = sessionImpl.CreateQuery(expression);
    query.SetParameters(expression.ParameterValuesByName);
    provider.SetResultTransformerAndAdditionalCriteria(
        query, expression, expression.ParameterValuesByName);
    return (EnumerableImpl)((AbstractQueryImpl2)query).Enumerable();
}

private static void SetParameters(this IQuery query, 
    IDictionary<string, Tuple<object, IType>> parameters)
{
    foreach (var parameterName in query.NamedParameters)
    {
        var param = parameters[parameterName];
        if (param.Item1 == null)
        {
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(param.Item2.ReturnedClass) &&
                param.Item2.ReturnedClass != typeof(string))
                query.SetParameterList(parameterName, null, param.Item2);
            else query.SetParameter(parameterName, null, param.Item2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (param.Item1 is IEnumerable && !(param.Item1 is string))
                query.SetParameterList(parameterName, (IEnumerable)param.Item1);
            else if (param.Item2 != null)
                query.SetParameter(parameterName, param.Item1, param.Item2);
            else query.SetParameter(parameterName, param.Item1);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to wrap it in a using statement to ensure the reader is closed:

```
using (var results = session.Query<Fark>().Take(50).Where(x => x.Enabled).Stream())
{
    results.ForEach(x => writer.WriteLine(x.ToCsv()));
}
```

Comment: Out of the box, this solution does not work. If you copy paste it in Visual Studio 12, NH 3.2, you get build errors. Can you prove this piece of code actually does stream and just not enumerates over a collection already in memory?

Comment: This was done with NH 4.0.0.4000, updated the answer. You can verify that it's working by watching the memory footprint of a process querying a large data set. If its buffering, memory usage will skyrocket, if it's streaming, it will remain constant. This is how I verified it was working.

Comment: If we switch to NH 4, I'll give it a go. Thx for the update

Answer (score 1):

Ayende says this:

> We still have the problem of memory consumption, though. The session
>   will keep track of all the loaded objects, and if we load a lot of
>   data, it will eventually blow out with an out of memory exception.

This is likely to be the cause. Did you ensure that the session does not track the objects? Try selecting not entities but some member of them to test this.

Comment: Yes, I've verified that the session is not tracking the objects. It is very clearly the case that NHibernate is retrieving the entire result set from the database before returning any results to the calling method. NHibernate is just the wrong tool for this kind of work, I think, so I've migrated to using Dapper for these types of operations.